# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hero_first'

Tags: python

I keep getting this, have no idea how to make it work, I'm kinda new at python coding and this is giving me a headacke. Could not find any answer at all so please, just tell me what to do

'''
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
# Variables

```
# Player
class Player(object):
    health = random.randint(70,100)
    strength = random.randint(70,80)
    defence = random.randint(45,55)
    speed = random.randint(40,50)
    luck = random.randint(40,50)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg

# Beast
class Beast(object):
    health = random.randint(60,90)
    strength = random.randint(60,90)
    defence = random.randint(40,60)
    speed = random.randint(40,60)
    luck = random.randint(25,40)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(Beast, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg

def begin():
    print("\nHero","          Beast"
"\nHealth:",    Player.health, "    Health:", Beast.health,
"\nStrength:",  Player.strength, "  Strength:",Beast.strength,
"\nDefence:",   Player.defence, "   Defence:", Beast.defence,
"\nSpeed:",     Player.speed, "     Speed:", Beast.speed,
"\nLuck:", Player.luck, "      Luck:", Beast.luck)
    print("\nBEGIN FIGHT")

def round_stat():
    print("Hero","          Beast",
    "\nHealth:", Player.health,"    Health:", Beast.health)

def who_move():
    hero_first = 1
    if Player.speed > Beast.speed:
        hero_first = 1
    elif Player.speed < Beast.speed:
        hero_first = 0
    else:
        if Player.luck > Beast.luck:
            hero_first = 1
        else:
            hero_first = 0



begin()

round_stat()

who_move()

if who_move().hero_first == 1:
    print("SUPPPPPPP")
```

'''

Comment: `who_move` function doesn't return anything explicitly, so it returns `None` implicitly. This is why you are getting an error, you are tring to use an attribute of the return walue of `who_move`.

Comment: WOW IT WORKED, thanks a bunch, never seen return() used in python before so I would never had thought of that

Answer (score 0):

`who_move()` is function, not an object. So you can not access variable inside function.
So the quickest solution is set the `hero_first` as global:

```
def who_move():
    global hero_first
    hero_first = 1    

who_move()

if hero_first == 1:
    print("SUPPPPPPP")
```

and then I got:

```
dubak@dubak-thinkpad:~/projects/$ python3 test.py 
SUPPPPPPP
```

or rewrite the `who_move` function so it is returning directly value of `hero_first`. Something like this:

```
def who_move():
    hero_first = None

    if 2 > 1:
        hero_first = 1

    return hero_first

if who_move() == 1:
    print("SUPPPPPPP")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the internal variables of a function using the `.` syntax. If you want that data to be accessible outside of the function, `return` it:

```
def who_move():
    if Player.speed > Beast.speed:
        return 1
    elif Player.speed < Beast.speed:
        return 0
    else:
        if Player.luck > Beast.luck:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Then, use it like:

```
if who_move() == 1
```

The other answer mentions `global`, but I would **not** use that here. Use of `global` should be limited, as it has a general tendency of making your code harder to maintain and understand.